# Chamar uma tag section sem exibir o ID na URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de eu chamar um `id` de uma section `HTML` sem exibir por exemplo na URL um `#id`, segue uma print abaixo para ajudar no entendimento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de chamar a tag section `Sobre` através de um `button` ou uma tag `<a>` sem exibir na URL o `#sobre`, isso é possível?

Código da Section

```html
<a href="#sobre">Sobre</a>

<section id="sobre">
  <!-- Conteudo da section... -->
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com jQuery é possível usando `preventDefault()` e `.animate`. O `preventDefault()` irá evitar que o link altere a URL da página, porque ele cancela o evento do link.

```js
$(function(){
   
   $("[href^='#']").click(function(e){
      
      e.preventDefault();
      
      // pega o href que é o id da section
      var id = $(this).attr("href");
      
      $('html').animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top})
   });
   
});
```

```css
section{
   margin: 500px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#sobre">Sobre</a>

<section id="sobre">
  section
</section>
```

O seletor `"[href^='#']"` irá buscar os elementos onde o atributo `href` inicia-se com `#`.

**Com JS puro:**

Pode usar `.scrollIntoView()`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   var ancoras = document.querySelectorAll("[href^='#']");
   
   for(var x=0; x<ancoras.length; x++){
      
      ancoras[x].onclick = function(e){
         
         e.preventDefault();

         // pega o href que é o id da section
         var id = this.getAttribute("href");
         
         document.querySelector(id).scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});

      }
      
   }
  
});
```

```css
section{
   margin: 500px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#sobre">Sobre</a>

<section id="sobre">
  section
</section>
```

As opções do `.scrollIntoView()`:

`block: 'start'`: o scroll vai ao início do elemento.
`behavior: 'smooth'`: o scroll vai de forma suave.

Comment: Obrigado @Sam deu certo aqui!